# Gitlab ci Oauth authentification do nothing

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to install gitlab ci to work with my gitlab installation.

I configure in gitlab a new Oauth application with this callback : http://ci.vikindie.fr/user_sessions/callback

I update my gitlab.rb to add theses lines :

```
external_url "http://code.vikindie.fr"
ci_external_url "http://ci.vikindie.fr"

gitlab_ci['gitlab_server'] = { 'url' => 'http://code.vikindie.fr', 'app_id' => "xxxxxxx", 'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxx'}
```

xxxxx is replace with gitlab code authentification.

Now, when i'm connecting to gitlab-ci, it's connect through gitlab and redirect to gitlab-ci with the callback url but it does nothing else. And i can't access to gitlab-ci home. If i retry, it does exactly the same, yet and yet ... I stuck on this page that demand to login on gitlab

I check the error.log of gitlab and gitlab-ci and nothing appear. (it's an omnibus install 7.8.2)

Vianney

Comment: "It’s appear the problem is the DNS resolution. I add in my `/etc/hosts` code.vikindie.fr and ci.vikindie.fr and now the authentication works." From your own answer: https://forum.gitlab.com/t/solved-7-8-2-gitlab-ci-oauth-authentification-do-nothing/357/2 ;)